# How to fix 'struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 24 bytes' to unpack tcp packet?

Tags: python, sockets, server

So I'm trying to unpack packets as they come in and display them. But I ran across this error that i'm not understanding. Maybe I just lack in understanding of unpacking packets in the right format but if you can point me in the right direction thank you

```
'! H H L L H H H H H H', data[:24])
 struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 24 bytes
```

So I tried to change the format types to bytes, unsigned long but idk because another error came out

```
        import socket
        import struct

        TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
        TCP_PORT = 4200
        BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        MESSAGE = b"01111001"

        TAB_1 = '\t - '
        TAB_2 = '\t\t - '
        TAB_3 = '\t\t\t - '
        TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t - '

        DATA_TAB_1 = '\t   '
        DATA_TAB_2 = '\t\t   '
        DATA_TAB_3 = '\t\t\t   '
        DATA_TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t   '

        def main():
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
            s.send(MESSAGE)

            while True:
                data, addr= s.recvfrom(65535)
                src_port, dest_port, sequence, acknowledgment, flag_urg, flag_ack, flag_psh, flag_rst, flag_syn, flag_fin = struct.unpack(
                    '! H H L L H H H H H H', data[:24])
                print(TAB_1 + 'TCP Segment:')
                print(TAB_2 + 'Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}'.format(src_port, dest_port))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Sequence: {}, Acknowledgment: {}'.format(sequence, acknowledgment))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Flags:')
                print(TAB_3 + 'URG: {}, ACK: {}, PSH: {}'.format(flag_urg, flag_ack, flag_psh))
                print(TAB_3 + 'RST: {}, SYN: {}, FIN:{}'.format(flag_rst, flag_syn, flag_fin))



        # Unpack IPv4 packet
        def ipv4_packet(data):
            version_header_length = data[0]
            version = version_header_length >> 4
            header_length = (version_header_length * 15) * 4
            ttl, proto, src, target = struct.unpack('! 8x BB 2x 4s 4s', data[:24])
            return version, header_length, ttl, proto, ipv4(src), ipv4(target), data[header_length: ]

        # Return properly formatted IPv4 address
        def ipv4(addr):
            return '.'.join(map(str, addr))

        # Unpack TCP segment
        def tcp_segment(data):
            (src_port, dest_port, sequence, acknowledgement, offset_reserved_flags) = struct.unpack('! H H L L H', data[:14])
            offset = (offset_reserved_flags >> 12) * 4
            flag_urg = (offset_reserved_flags & 32) >> 5
            flag_ack = (offset_reserved_flags & 16) >> 4
            flag_psh = (offset_reserved_flags & 8) >> 3
            flag_rst = (offset_reserved_flags & 4) >> 2
            flag_syn = (offset_reserved_flags & 2) >> 1
            flag_fin = offset_reserved_flags & 1


        main()
```

Comment: `data` is less than 24 bytes. You need to call `recvfrom()` in a loop until you get 24 bytes.

Comment: When you use a TCP socket, you don't get the TCP header in the data, you just get the payload. If you want to access the complete packet, you need to use a raw socket, or use the `libpcap` library.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I can give you links I found with google: https://pypi.org/project/libpcap/ https://pypi.org/project/pcapy/

Comment: Oh so I used socket.SOCK_RAW but was getting an OS error. Whats the alternative for windows without using libpcap

Comment: Don't know how to do it on Windows. Raw sockets can only be used by a priveleged account or application, ordinary users aren't allowed to see packet headers.

Comment: Why are you writing this yourself instead of using something like Wireshark?

Comment: A project for something

Comment: [Microsoft documentation on raw sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2)